# How to generate key value macro from csv file?

Tags: datatool, csv

I have a CSV file with key-value pairs, and I want to be able to read the file into latex, and generate macros to access the values.  Here is my current attempt with `datatool`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}

\newcommand{\loadmap}[2][map]{%
    \DTLloaddb{#1}{#2}%
    \DTLforeach{#1}{\Key=Key,\Value=Value}{%
        \expandafter\def\csname #1\Key\endcsname{\Value}}}

\newcommand{\loadmaptest}[2][map]{%
    \DTLloaddb{#1}{#2}%
    \DTLforeach{#1}{\Key=Key,\Value=Value}{\Key,\Value\\}}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
    Key,Value
    firstkey,0.002
    secondkey,1.0
    thirdkey,4
\end{filecontents}  

\loadmap{testdata.csv}
\mapfirstkey,\mapsecondkey,\mapthirdkey\\

\loadmaptest[second]{testdata.csv}

\end{document}
```

You will see that the output is something like:

```
4,4,4
firstkey,0.002
secondkey,1.0
thirdkey,4
```

So, while the `DTLforeach` is correctly iterating through the CSV file when directly displaying the results, the generation of the macros is incorrect.  In particular, it correctly generates the macro names as `\mapfirstkey`, etc. but the value for all of them is the last value in the keys.  I suspect this has something to do with me incorrectly expanding macros...

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `\edef` instead `\def`.

Comment: @esdd Easy-peasy.  Thank you so much.  If you post as a solution I will accept it.

Comment: @esdd Actually, another issue is that the keys can't have numbers in them.  Is there a trick to have the `\edef` accept numbers?

Comment: `\expandafter\edef\csname macro123\endcsname{definition}`, or am I missing the point of your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to expand `\Value`, otherwise the defined macros would contain it and not its value.

If you plan to use non alphabetic characters in the keys, I suggest to implement a `\usevar` command.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Key,Value
firstkey,0.002
secondkey,1.0
thirdkey,4
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\loadmap}[2][map]{%
  \DTLloaddb{#1}{#2}%
  \DTLforeach{#1}{\Key=Key,\Value=Value}{%
    \expandafter\def\csname#1\Key\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\Value}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\usevar}[2]{\csname #1#2\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\loadmap{\jobname.csv}

\usevar{map}{firstkey}, \usevar{map}{secondkey}, \usevar{map}{thirdkey}  

\end{document}
```

With the help of `xparse` and `expl3` this can be made more efficient.

Note that the `\usevar` command can use an optional argument, but it remains fully expandable.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Key,Value
firstkey,0.002
secondkey,1.0
thirdkey,4
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\loadmap}{O{map}m}
 {
  \jlperla_keyvalue_assign:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{O{map}m}
 {
  \prop_item:cn { l_jlperla_keyvalue_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__jlperla_keyvalue_key_tl
\tl_new:N \l__jlperla_keyvalue_Value_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jlperla_keyvalue_assign:nn
 {
  \prop_clear_new:c { l_jlperla_keyvalue_#1_prop }
  \DTLloaddb{#1}{#2}
  \DTLforeach{#1}
   {
    \l__jlperla_keyvalue_key_tl = Key,
    \l__jlperla_keyvalue_Value_tl = Value
   }
   {
    \prop_put:cVV
     { l_jlperla_keyvalue_#1_prop }
     \l__jlperla_keyvalue_key_tl
     \l__jlperla_keyvalue_Value_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { cVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\loadmap{\jobname.csv}

\usevar{firstkey}, \usevar[map]{secondkey}, \usevar{thirdkey}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great.  Though I can't figure out how to get the expl3 engine working with Miktex, so I will have to go with the easier one.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `\def` by `\edef`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}

\newcommand{\loadmap}[2][map]{%
    \DTLloaddb{#1}{#2}%
    \DTLforeach{#1}{\Key=Key,\Value=Value}{%
        \expandafter\edef\csname #1\Key\endcsname{\Value}}}% <- changed

\newcommand{\loadmaptest}[2][map]{%
    \DTLloaddb{#1}{#2}%
    \DTLforeach{#1}{\Key=Key,\Value=Value}{\Key,\Value\\}}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
    Key,Value
    firstkey,0.002
    secondkey,1.0
    thirdkey,4
\end{filecontents}  

\loadmap{testdata.csv}
\noindent
\mapfirstkey,\mapsecondkey,\mapthirdkey\\
\loadmaptest[second]{testdata.csv}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Because of a comment: While it is possible to use numbers in the key you have to use `\csname ...\endcsname in the code. So I do not recommend to use the following example. Maybe you can find better names for your keys.

\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{datatool,filecontents}

```
\newcommand{\loadmap}[2][map]{%
    \DTLloaddb{#1}{#2}%
    \DTLforeach{#1}{\Key=Key,\Value=Value}{%
        \expandafter\edef\csname #1\csname Key\endcsname\endcsname{\Value}}}

\newcommand{\loadmaptest}[2][map]{%
    \DTLloaddb{#1}{#2}%
    \DTLforeach{#1}{\Key=Key,\Value=Value}{\Key,\Value\\}}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
    Key,Value
    firstkey,0.002
    2key,1.0
    thirdkey,4
\end{filecontents}  

\loadmap{testdata.csv}
\noindent
\mapfirstkey,\csname map2key\endcsname ,\mapthirdkey\\
\loadmaptest[second]{testdata.csv}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An approach with `readarray` instead of `datatool`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}[2016-11-07]
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myfile.dat}
    Key,Value
    firstkey,0.002
    secondkey,1.0
    thirdkey,4
    4key, 77
\end{filecontents*}
\newcounter{mycount}
\newcommand\assigndat[1]{%
  \readarraysepchar{,}%
  \readdef{#1}\mydata%
  \readarray*\mydata\myarray[-,\ncols]%
  \setcounter{mycount}{0}%
  \whiledo{\themycount<\nrows}{%
    \stepcounter{mycount}%
    \edef\tmp{\myarray[\themycount,1]}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\xdef\expandafter\csname\tmp\endcsname{%
      \myarray[\themycount,2]}%
    }%
}
\newcommand\theKey[1]{\myarray[#1,1]}
\newcommand\theValue[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\assigndat{myfile.dat}
\theKey{1}: \theValue{\theKey{1}} or \theValue{Key}\par
\theKey{2}: \theValue{\theKey{2}} or \theValue{firstkey}\par
\theKey{3}: \theValue{\theKey{3}} or \theValue{secondkey}\par
\theKey{4}: \theValue{\theKey{4}} or \theValue{thirdkey}\par
\theKey{5}: \theValue{\theKey{5}} or \theValue{4key}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `pgffor` package loaded, one could loop through all the keys in one fell swoop as such:

```
\foreach\x in {2,...,\myarrayROWS}{\theKey{\x}: \theValue{\theKey{\x}}\par}
```